# Отдача функцией пути со слешом или без?

Tags: стандарт

Есть ли какое то соглашение о том, в каком формате должны отдаваться пути к директориям функциями/методами/константами, а именно со слешом на конце или без?

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю о соглашениях, но посмотрели бы на свой код. Если там постоянно нужно писать что то вида

```
get_path + "/" + filename
```

то явно лучше, что бы функция возвращала уже со слешом. Кроме того, она может ставить сразу правильный слеш.

Но с другой стороны, слеш всегда легко добавить, а вот убрать иногда может быть сложнее.

Посмотрим глубже. В msdn есть описание, что такое "path" и "dir".

[SetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx)

> The final character before the null character must be a backslash ('\').

то есть, четко понятно, что там должен быть слеш.

Если же в том же msdn почитать о путях, то там везде приводятся примеры без слеша Кроме случая, когда это диск - C:\ или любой другой.

Поэтому, мое предложение такое. Функция GetPath должна возвращать без слеша, а функция GetDir - со слешем. Понятно, что вторая может быть реализована через первую.

Comment: Как вы думаете имеет ли значение то что путь с двойным слешом остается рабочим(php), то есть:

//Со сшешом, '/root/foo/bar/'
$path = getPath();

// Будет рабочим
$slavePath = $path . '/config/main/';

// Не поставили слеш, все по прежнему работает
$slavePath = $path . 'config/main/';

//Без слеша, '/root/foo/bar'

// Будет рабочим
$slavePath = $path . '/config/main/';

// Не поставили слеш, уже все не работает
$slavePath = $path . 'config/main/';

Comment: >Не поставили слеш, уже все не работает

Это проблема уже ваша. Договоритесь, документируйте, следуйте соглашениям.

Для таких вот нерадивых - апач даже подстраивается, игнорируя двойные слэши. Нормальные файловые системы тоже. А как вы там внутри ваших похапе будете ковыряться, кого волнует?

Comment: Двойные слеши почти всегда игнорируются, кроме одного случая - в самом начале пути. Ссылка на [документацию](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html).

>  A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be treated as a single slash.